# using os:cmd and EOT symbol in the output

Tags: erlang, cmd

With my external program I create a PDF file, and try to pass to an erlang program. But the PDF contains EOT symbols. When the first EOT is reached, the transfer stops.

How I can pass the whole file?

added after sarnold,

```
os:cmd(io_lib:format("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib; 
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; /home/yola/progra/cpp/pdf/a.out ~s", ["Hello"]))
```

this doesnt return whole generated file. First EOT symbol encountered at 2305 pos and erlang got 2304 symbols, but file length 64xxx bytes.

Comment: You're going to have show some source code here -- I can't imagine how a single ASCII character could cause a "transfer" (between computers? processes? spaceships?) to fail. Try to demonstrate the problem with twenty to thirty lines of code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `os:cmd` function uses EOT to know when to stop reading from the external program; see [os.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/kernel/src/os.erl#L301).  So you'll have to do it in some other way, such as redirecting output to a file:

```
os:cmd(io_lib:format("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib; 
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; /home/yola/progra/cpp/pdf/a.out ~s > my.pdf", ["Hello"])),
{ok, MyPDF} = file:read_file("my.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks, for now, i replace every EOT to over symbol, insert meta info in the beginning of the generated file and parse in erlang and then change back. Thanks, for your suggestion.